# ggplot2, unwanted naming in Y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-manipulation

Let's say I have following data:

```r
df <- data.frame(
     "Values" = c("Gender","Gender","Marital Status","Marital Status","Age","Age"),
     "Mean"= c(0.6934877,  0.8536885,  0.8801737,  0.8998975, 54.6858177, 54.1486680),
     "By"= c("Urban", "Rural", "Urban","Rural","Urban", "Rural")
)
```

```r
df$Values <- factor(df$Values)

levels(df$Values)

df_groupby <- df %>%
      dplyr::group_by(Values)
```

Expected results on the y-axis  Gender, Marital Status, Age same as in `df`.  Many thanks in advance

I tried that without success

```r
ggplot(df_groupby , aes(Values, Mean)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
      coord_flip()
```

Comment: Could you give more details ? I don't understand tyour problem since, in my graph, I see the three categories you mention in the yaxis

Comment: Yeah, I want to see in Y- axsis  Gender, Marital Statues and Age, in the same order you see in  "Values" = c("Gender","Gender","Marital Status","Marital Status","Age","Age")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your answer to the comment, I slightly modified your workflow to construct the reproducible example.

```r
df <- data.frame(
  "Values" = c("Gender","Gender","Marital Status","Marital Status","Age","Age"),
  "Mean"= c(0.6934877,  0.8536885,  0.8801737,  0.8998975, 54.6858177, 54.1486680),
  "By"= c("Urban", "Rural", "Urban","Rural","Urban", "Rural"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
df_groupby <- df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Values) 

df_groupby$Values <- factor(df_groupby$Values, levels = unique(df$Values), ordered = TRUE)
```

If you want categories in the order of your values

```r
ggplot(df_groupby , aes(Values, Mean)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

If you want them in reverse order

```r
ggplot(df_groupby , aes(Values, Mean)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(df_groupby$Values)))
```

[image]

Comment: this works for the reverse df_groupby$Values <- factor(df_groupby$Values, levels = rev(unique(df$Values)), ordered = TRUE) , thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Set the factor levels manually in the wanted order. Then use e.g. `forcats::fct_rev` to reverse the order in the plot. BTW: `df_groupby` is not necessary. You can plot using `df`. Try this:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  "Values" = c("Gender","Gender","Marital Status","Marital Status","Age","Age"),
  "Mean"= c(0.6934877,  0.8536885,  0.8801737,  0.8998975, 54.6858177, 54.1486680),
  "By"= c("Urban", "Rural", "Urban","Rural","Urban", "Rural")
)

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

df$Values <- factor(df$Values, levels = c("Gender", "Marital Status", "Age"))

levels(df$Values)
#> [1] "Gender"         "Marital Status" "Age"

df_groupby <- df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Values)

ggplot(df_groupby , aes(forcats::fct_rev(Values), Mean)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>